# Trying to convert a web site to an executable file

Tags: html

I am trying to create a portfolio disc to sell my photos and to protect my work. I want to put my web site that i created into one exe so that my photos can't be stolen as an extra precaution. I know to use the webBrowser.navigate command with the internet controls but how do I add the web site directory to the exe to make it run in one file? I don't want to install it on the user's computer. Just operate the site's directory from the home page all through 1 exe file. I know its possible to do. I have seen apps like HTMLexe that will convert them for you but the free apps i have found won't allow the javascript and css files to run. Some won't even do it without buying the full premimum version of the software.  How can I code this myself?

Comment: Your photos can't be protected.  Too many snipping programs.  If they are visible, they can be captured.  Your best bet is to add a watermark to the photos.

Comment: I have taken precautions for that already by formatting the photos to be too small to print among other little things to prevent it. I just want to combine the site together into 1 exe file.

Comment: It won't work on a Mac and maybe issues depending on what version of .Net and such is installed. But anyway it won't solve your issue because people can still do a print screen or use another tool to capture the images, or hell even break open the exe and get them. Your best bet is just to send watermarked lower resolution files to them along with an order form.

Comment: Just save the HTML site on disc and be done with it. (a) You cannot protect the images in your application. (b) You get a platform independent output. (c) You can spend the time saved on things that generate cash. Make the images lo-res _and_ watermarked and move on is my suggestion.